# Динамическое построение стилей SCSS

Tags: scss, ionic3

Если не так выразился, переименуйте тему
Всё происходит в Ionic3

В ходе построения дерева, получаю такие стили:
*Сразу пример как хочу*

```
.level-0 { padding-left: (0*5)px }
.level-1 { padding-left: (1*5)px }
.level-2 { padding-left: (2*5)px }
.level-N { padding-left: (N*5)px }
```

Конечное N заранее не известно

Не смог сгуглить, можно в SCSS что-то наподобие?:

```
.level-("\d") { padding-left: ($1*5)px }
```

---

Так как ни чего не сгуглил, пошел другим путем

HTML

```
<ion-list *ngIf="items.length" attr.indent="{{lvl*5}}">
```

SCSS

```
ion-list[indent] {
  padding-left: attr(indent px);
}
```

Тут атрибут создается и прописывается нужное число, но сам падинг ругается что не может высчитать
Пробовал px убирать в стилях и прописывать в html, результат тот же

---

Далее сгуглил такой вариант
HTML

```
<ion-list *ngIf="items.length" style="--indent: 10">
```

SCSS

```
ion-list[indent] {
  padding-left: calc(5px * var(--indent));
}
```

Ну или так:
HTML

```
<ion-list *ngIf="items.length" style="--indent: 10px">
```

SCSS

```
ion-list[indent] {
  padding-left: var(--indent);
}
```

Тут все работает, но я не могу за место 10-ки подставить свое значение lvl
Ionic тупо сразу игнорит - style пустой формируется

---

Итого: Нужно для каждого уровня вложенности свой отступ, основываясь на глубину погружения

Как то так

Comment: Может такой вариант подойдет? - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/zr3Lu2y6/

Comment: К сожалению, я так уже вкостылил, только я взял 100 на перебздеть, но это как то не тру

Comment: Тогда только javascript